# Qt - notifications without tray icon, possible?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, notifications

I'm writing a C++ Qt desktop appliaction.

Is it possible to show Skype=like notifcations in Qt, **without** creating a tray icon?

All notification reference I found require a tray icon, which I do not want to create.

The notifications should show when the application is opened and when it is minimized.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show ubuntu (linux) notifications with Qt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818014/show-ubuntu-linux-notifications-with-qt)

Comment: Specify your target OS please.

Comment: @AleksandrKravets Currently windows 7, but may be extended to linux in the furtue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create popup class and show it somwhere on the desktop with always on top flag. Notification may also be a widget

Comment: @sara: Nobody wants to do your work, so please show us some effort. For example, write a [sscce](http://sscce.org) and tell us what gone wrong while you were writing it. [Official documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/) is always a good place to start.

Comment: The notification should be a notification like the other notifications, not just a random window.

Comment: @LtWorf Skype does not use system notifications and it was given as example. In perfect world - sure it would be great to use system notifications, however there are so many differences between platforms that it sometimes makes it impossible to achieve behavaiour you need.

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE**: it seems this isn't working with recent versions of Qt. A workaround I found to make this work was to, after creating the QSystemTrayIcon:

- Call `show()`
- Display the desired message with `showMessage`
- Call `hide()`

This works OK for me.

---

Create a `QSystemTrayIcon` but never call `show()` on it. Then you can use `QSystemTrayIcon::showMessage` to display your popup.

Comment: but then I won't be able to style the notfication, and it will look like system notification, no?

Comment: Tried this on Mac and Windows (Qt 5.3, OS X 10.10 / Win 8.1): the message is only displayed after calling show() so this seems to be no valid answer to the question.

Comment: If you never call `show()` on it, this won't work. But you can call `show()`, then `showMessage`, then `hide()` and you will have a similar effect.

Answer (score 2):

a little late but you might be interested in this library
https://github.com/Snorenotify/Snorenotify/

> Snorenotify is a multi platform Qt notification framework. Using a plugin system it is possible to create notifications with many different notification systems on Windows, Unix and Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue as OP ( But with Python!! ), [Romario](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2507567/rom%C3%A1rio)'s answer got me half way to what i wanted.

In my scenario i have a sys-tray tool where i enforce only one being alive via lockfile. However user feedback requested that if they try launching while already open i provide some sort of feedback.

What i found was on Windows - the Romarios answer will lead icons persisting in the systray - if you call `setVisible(False)` before the `show()` it will prevent icons appearing/acculumating in the sys-tray :)

My complete sample is

```
class SimpleNotifier(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def notify_running(self):
        tray_icon = QtGui.QIcon(Params.TRAY_ICON)
        self.setIcon(tray_icon)
        self.setVisible(False)
        self.show()
        self.showMessage("Hi User", "Application already inside your sys-tray", QtGui.QIcon(Params.TRAY_ICON))

def notify():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    notify = HUBController.SimpleNotifier()
    notify.notify_running()
    app.exit()

notify()
```

*and yes i did sign up for an account after lurking for years just to make this post :
:)*